# What is IE 7 doing to my unordered lists?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7

It seems IE 7 is not rendering the lists inline.  Any help?

http://riemserdental.com/test2

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe IE7 recognizes `display: table` and `table-cell`.

Use a different means of making a horizontal menu if you need it IE7 compatible.

Answer (score 1):

You are using display:table-cell for the list-items. That's CSS2 and I'm pretty sure that it's not supported by IE7.

Answer (score 0):

As the other 2 answers said, IE won't recognize display table.
You probably want to say display:inline and list-style:none